# Slayer Exciter Circuit

Tags: mosfet, driver, 555, diagram

[image]

- R1  = 2Ω
- R2 >= 22kΩ
- D2 = 1N4148, or 1N400x (x is a number)
- U1 = [MIC4452](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MIC4452) (MIC4452YN is the through-hole version)
- Q1 = [2SK2542](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/2SK2542F/?qs=EEns8I54Y6A%252b1RmCFs2azA%3D%3D)

So basically I want to run the circuit from a NE555 timer because I don't have the MIC4452 to drive the MOSFET. I will be using an [IRFP460](http://www.futurlec.com/Transistors/IRFP460.shtml) MOSFET.
I have no clue how to wire everything up ... and other components I need.
If someone could walk me through the connections for the circuit... ?

Comment: Not really, this is a question and answer site so you should do your own research about how to connect components up and how dangerous the output voltage could be in the wrong hands. Or maybe even speak to the guy who drew the circuit?

Comment: *I have no clue* Then why not get a clue first, there is much information to be found if you just go look for it.

Answer (score 0):

The dots indicate negative feedback on windings if you show the stray capacitance correctly between primary and secondary.

Since both MOSFET common source parts are inverting, so it won't work .The condition for oscillation is that the feedback must be positive in the loop and with the coil inverted, you have three inverters.

Therefore to make it oscillate, the output coil must be non-inverting , i.e. both dots at top or bottom. (same thing)

The Q of the coils is critical to increase L/R ratio and achieve the turns ratio and may be limited in primitive coil designs to <100.  Tesla coils were high Q using air coils with special winding methods.

The resonant frequency is determined by the LC product with a classic formula, you should look up.  That's about all I'll say for now.